Java: How to timeout the current thread
I have a multithreaded Java application that uses ThreadLocal fields to keep the threads isolated from each other. As part of this application I also have a requirement to implement timeouts on certain functions to prevent DOS attacks.
I'm looking for a way to time out a Java function that is running in the current thread
I've seen plenty of solutions such as How to timeout a thread which will create a Future to execute some code, launch it in a new thread and and wait for it to complete. I want to make it work the other way round.
Consider the following code, which will be run in a multi-threaded environment:
class MyClass {
    // ThreadLocal is not private so callback can access it
    ThreadLocal<AtomicInteger> counter = ThreadLocal.withInitial(AtomicInteger::new);

    public void entry(Function<?, ?> callback) {
        counter.get().set(10);                      // Calling thread performs set up
        I_need_a_timeout(callback, 110);            // Call a function which might take a long time
        int result = counter.get().get();           // If there is no time out this will be 110
    }

    private void I_need_a_timeout(Function<?, ?> callback, int loop) {
        while (loop-- >= 0) {
            counter.get().incrementAndGet();
            callback.apply(null);                   // This may take some time
        }
    }
}

I need to be able to terminate I_need_a_timeout if it runs for too long, but if I were to execute it in a future then it would have it's own thread and therefore it's own instance of AtomicInteger so the value read by the calling code would always be the value I initialise it to (in this case 10)
Update: I've updated the sample code to be closer to my real application. The client passes a function to I_need_a_timeout that could take any amount of time to return (or potentially may never return), so polling solutions won't work

What do you mean by "if the function runs for too long"? Can't you just add an additional condition in your while-loop such as an atomic flag? while (loop-- >= 0 && enableINeedATimeout)

@darclander, Unfortunately I can't. The sample code I've given is a (very much) simplified version of what I'm dealing with. The actual code includes a callback function that I can't control can may waiting on external systems.

Can I ask why you want to do it this way? Why not execute the work on a thread pool and cancel the future if it's taking too long?

@lance-java, I need to do it this way so that the ThreadLocal variables are always read from the same thread. If I_need_a_timeout was run from thread in the thread pool then counter.get() will return different instances of AtomicInteger depending on who is calling it

Your request seems to come down to how to invoke the externally-provided callback, limiting its execution time, without performing the execution in a different thread.  Is that right?

Does this answer your question? How do you kill a Thread in Java?

The operation in the callback.apply(null) call must check some kind of variable, for example Thread.isInterrupted(), for this to work. There is no other way to in Java. This is by design.

@John Bollinger - Basically yes. I'm going to execute some code and that will have a call back. Since the call back could block I need to limit it's execution, but I can't change into a new thread to do it.

Then you're out of luck, @Stormcloud.  You need to revisit the "I can't change into a new thread to do it" part.  While a thread is executing a callback, that's what it's doing.  That thread is occupied, so if you need it's operation to be managed or controlled, apart from according to the code it is executing, then that can only be done via a different thread.

@JohnBollinger I think, the OP understood that canceling “can only be done via a different thread”. The point of the question is that the other thread should not perform the operation but the cancelation, unlike most examples (cite: “I want to make it work the other way round”).

You can straight-forwardly create a future whose operation is executed in the current thread and cancel it from another thread. E.g.
public class CancelCurrentThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(var canceler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)) {
            for(long timeout: List.of(500, 1500)) {
                FutureTask<String> task
                    = new FutureTask<>(CancelCurrentThread::operation);
                System.out.println("Timeout: " + timeout + "ms");
                canceler.schedule(
                    () -> task.cancel(true), timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                task.run();
                try {
                    System.out.println("Result: " + task.get());
                }
                catch(CancellationException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Canceled");
                }
                catch(InterruptedException|ExecutionException e) {
                    System.out.println("Failed: " + e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
  
    static String operation() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("performing operation in " + Thread.currentThread());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return "result";
    }
}

Timeout: 500ms
performing operation in Thread[#1,main,5,main]
Canceled
Timeout: 1500ms
performing operation in Thread[#1,main,5,main]
Result: result

It’s important to keep in mind that the same restrictions as with futures from an ExecutorService apply. To return quickly upon cancelation, the operation must respond to interruption, either by using operations which abort on interruption (like the sleep in the example) or by polling Thread.interrupted() in reasonable intervals.

A continuous isInterrupted() check inside I_need_a_timeout function would do the trick or defining a Volatile or Atomic Boolean variable to keep checking for timeout will also help

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The OP's problem seems to be that the implementation of callback is not under their control, so they can't put isInterrupted() calls (or anything else) there.  They are concerned that execution of callback.apply() may hang or take too long.

ExecutorService time-out does work
The Question you linked does provide a solution.

I'm looking for a way to time out a Java function that is running in the current thread

The try-with-resources syntax with an executor service blocks until the background task(s) complete. So you get the same effect as running that task within the same thread.

ThreadLocal is necessary, … The problem with a Callable is that it runs in another thread, and therefore pulls the wrong object out of the Threadlocal.

Whatever objects are needed by the background thread can be passed to the constructor of that task instance.
In the example below, the final Integer start , final Integer limit arguments could come from ThreadLocal vars.
Example code
Define your task as a Callable. Submit that task to an executor service while specifying a time-out.
When submitting via invokeAll, you get a list of Future objects. Check each Future for isCancelled to detect the time-out having expired.
In your example, the AtomicInteger is unnecessary. The task should be implementing its own integer number, then returning result via the Future.
And no need for ThreadLocal.
class Incrementation implements Callable < Integer >
{
    Integer start , limit ;

    // Constructor
    Incrementation ( final Integer start , final Integer limit ) 
    {
        this.start = start ;
        this.limit = limit ;
    }

    Integer call() 
    {
        int x = this.start ;
        for ( int index = 1 ; index <= this.limit ; index ++ )
        {
            x = x + 1 ;
        }
        return Integer.valueOf( x ) ;
    }

}

Usage:
List < Incrementation > tasks = List.of( new Incrementation( 1 , 100 ) ;
try (
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors. … ;
)
{
    List < Future < Integer > > futures = executorService.invokeAll( tasks , 20 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) ;
    Future< Integer > future = futures.getFirst() ;
    if ( future.isCancelled() ) 
    {
        … // Likely caused by time-out expiring. 
    }
}

See this Answer by Drew Wills with additions by me.

My example is a little contrived to keep the code short. In the real application ThreadLocal is necessary, because there a are lot of threads being fired, but it holds a rather more complex type than an AtomicInteger. The problem with a Callable is that it runs in another thread, and therefore pulls the wrong object out of the Threadlocal. The linked answer was one of the code samples I'd read but discounted because the executing code runs in the wrong thread.

Perhaps I'm reading the question incorrectly, but this seems to describe exactly the approach that the OP explicitly rejects ("I want to make it work the other way round.").

@JohnBollinger I am trying to show that the solution rejected by the OP does work, and it works rather neatly. I added more prose to make that point more clearly. Thank you for your Comment.

@Basil Bourque: In your solution, even when the executor job timeouts and getFirst returns, the loop inside Incrementation#call will continue to run in the background. Right? So the actual operation itself will not timeout. It's thread will continue to run, not be stopped by a ThreadDeath exception or something like that. I'm not sure if that is acceptable for the poster.

@Basil Bourque: Thank you for taking the time to help. ThreadLocal variables are required in the real application (they are used by the callback function). Redefining the problem is not an option. As I understand your proposed solution, Thread1 will create an instance of Incrementation, it will then create a Future for that instance and then wait on the instance in the try block. Thread2 will be created by the ExecutorService to run the code in the Incrementation class.  Sorry, This is the opposite of what I asked for - Thread1 must execute Incrementation and Thread2 must poll the Future
